# Is it the elgin threading tool

Tags: us4636489

I looked at the patent 4636489 in google patents and found inconsistencies.
Is it eglin or elgin? 
In the patent title it is spelled one way and in the text the other way. 
How should it be?

Comment: This patent has lapsed and is no longer enforceable anyways.  What is your concern?

Answer (score 1):

The patent title has very little of anything to do with the enforceable part of the patent: The Claims.   Dwelling over a patent title, it's abstract or even description is a moot point.  Go straight to the claims and read them, if you have any dispute or questions, update your post.